# Android grid view background image issue

Tags: android, gridview, image-scaling

I am a beginner. I am actually creating a grid view of about 30 items, and setting a single big image as background for grid view. So instead of setting one image for every grid element, how can I set a single image for background of grid view and make it work for every screen size so that image will be scaled according to the grid and I can get click on every date. Posting a sample calendar image,

[image: calender and setting this image for background of grid, so that I can ghet click on every date]

Comment: paste your xml screen

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file, ImageView tag, write two new lines below:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```